# What is the function that satisfies $\int_0^x f(t) dt=constant$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, integral-equations

$$\int_0^x f(t) dt=constant$$

What is the function that satisfies this condition ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ a function of $x$?

Comment: yes! a function of x, f(x)

Answer (score 7):

Differentiating both sides of $$\int_0^x f(t) dt=constant$$ using Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus, as mentioned by Omnomnomnom in his comment,( or Leibnitz Rule as I had earlier written),
we get
$$f(x)=0$$

Comment: This is more commonly referred to as the "fundamental theorem of calculus" than the "Leibniz Rule"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The above result can be arrived at using both the "fundamental theorem of calculus" and the "Leibniz Rule".

Comment: sure, and the product rule can be derived using the multivariable chain-rule.  However, since the asker is likely an introductory calculus student, it is better to use the more accessible result.

Comment: I agree. You're right.

Comment: OP hasn't ever specified that $f$ is continuous. If it isn't, you can't apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Wojowu Since OP has not mentioned, I have considered $f(t)$ to be continuous in the interval $[0,x]$ else I don't think the integration would be strictly defined in that interval and if there was at all a discontinuity, the integration would have to be divided into continuous intervals and the OP would have surely mentioned that. As for example, $\int^{\pi}_{0} tan x dx$ cannot be computed as such without using improper integral since $tan x$ is not defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Riemann integral is defined for any bounded function defined on the whole interval. Then it can be shown that this integral exists iff the function is continuous at all points of this interval, except possibly a set of measure zero. That being said, it is possible to Riemann-integrate many functions which aren't continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote the continuous function:

$$G(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$$

Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$$\frac{d}{dx}G(x)=f(x)$$

When $G(x)=C$, $$\frac{d}{dx}G(x)=0=f(x)$$

Comment: OP hasn't ever specified that $f$ is continuous. If it isn't, you can't apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Because OP has never said $f(t)$ has to be a continuous function, there are more possible functions than a constant zero. For example, if we define $$f(t)=1\text{ for $t\in\Bbb Z$}, 0\text{ otherwise}$$
We get a nonconstant function integral of which is $0$ on every integral. More generally, any function which is non-zero on a discrete set of points will work.

But these aren't all functions: take, for example, [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). It is only nonzero on a set of measure zero, and is Riemann-integrable, hence its integral over any interval is again zero.

If we limit ourselves to Riemann-integrable functions, I believe this is the necessary and sufficient condition:

> $f(t)=0$ for every $t$ at which $f$ is continuous.

Since Riemann-integrable function must be continuous outside a set of measure zero, this condition is enough to conclude $f$ has integral $0$ on every interval. Conversely, if $f(t_0)>0$ at a point of continuity $t_0$ ($f(t_0)<0$ is treated similarly), then on some open interval we have $f(t)>\frac{f(t_0)}{2}>0$, so on this interval the integral will increase, so it won't be constant.

If we allow more general integrals (Lebesgue measurable) then I believe an equivalent condition would be that $f(t)$ is non-zero only on a set of measure zero, but I don't know enough about Lebesgue-integrability to say that with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the constant is zero,Because:

$$ constant =   \int_0^0 f(x) dx = 0$$
Can you conclude now?

Comment: @SimonS: on the opposite ! It shows that such a function does not exist, unless the constant is $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, my mistake

Comment: if constant is not zero and x>0, what about this case?

Comment: @user286255: this is answered here.